# How to change colour of scrollbar when calling flashScrollIndicator() in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just discovered how to properly use flashScrollIndicator but I'm having trouble changing the colour of the scroller when it flashes. I want to change it to red. This is what I have for my function to flash the scroller when the viewTable loads up:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()
}
```

I also was able to create a function that actually changes the scroller but only when the user actually scrolls, not when the scroller simply flashes. If its any help, this is the code for it:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let verticalIndicator = scrollView.subviews.last as? UIImageView
    verticalIndicator?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to put those two pieces together. If you add the color-changing code to `viewDidAppear`, it should work just like it does in `scrollViewDidScroll`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let verticalIndicator = tableView.subviews.last as? UIImageView
    verticalIndicator?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()
}
```

While this is possible, I don't recommend it for a few reasons:

1. It's fragile. Since this isn't a readily available public API, there's no guarantee this will work in future iOS versions.
2. It's probably a bad design choice. Do you really want to point the user's attention to a differently colored scroll bar? Most users familiar with other apps are used to the default look of the scroll bars, so it communicates their position in the view without much extra attention. Also it doesn't look very nice when I just tried it.

The alternative solution is to simply set the scroll indicator style to one of the available options (`default`, `white`, or `black`).

```
tableView.indicatorStyle = .default
```

Comment: Okay thanks and I will definitely look into what you are saying